How to find the local maximum
I write a VBA code to find local maximum in certain scenario and it works perfectly. However, in a bit changed scenario it gave me the maximum value, (not the one in circle) and I can't figure out how to change the code to gave me the value I need (the one in circle)?
Plot of data with "negative effect"

Plot of data with no "negative effect"

I tried to do something with derivative and slope but doesn't succeed.
Here is the original code without derivative:
Option Explicit

Sub FindFirstPeakInSheet(wsSource As Worksheet, ByRef firstPeak As Double, ByRef foundPeak As Boolean)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Initialize the foundPeak flag to False
    foundPeak = False

    ' Find the last row with data in column B
    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Clear the auxiliary column (column C)
    wsSource.Range("C1:C" & lastRow).ClearContents

    ' Loop through the range in column B and fill auxiliary column with peaks
    For i = 2 To lastRow - 1
        If IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(i, 2).Value) And _
           IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(i - 1, 2).Value) And _
           IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value) Then

            If wsSource.Cells(i, 2).Value > wsSource.Cells(i - 1, 2).Value And _
               wsSource.Cells(i, 2).Value > wsSource.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value And _
               wsSource.Cells(i, 2).Value > 2 Then
                wsSource.Cells(i, 3).Value = wsSource.Cells(i, 2).Value ' Fill auxiliary column with peaks
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ' Find the first peak in the auxiliary column
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(i, 3).Value) And wsSource.Cells(i, 3).Value <> "" Then
            firstPeak = wsSource.Cells(i, 3).Value
            foundPeak = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub FindFirstPeakTest2()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsResults As Worksheet
    Dim firstPeak As Double
    Dim foundPeak As Boolean
    Dim resultRow As Long

    ' Set the results sheet (change "Results" to your desired results sheet name)
    Set wsResults = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")

    ' Initialize the result row for output in the Results sheet, starting from D3
    resultRow = 3

    ' Loop through each worksheet in the workbook except the Results sheet and the specified sheets
    For Each wsSource In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsSource.Name <> "Results" And wsSource.Name <> "Parameters" And wsSource.Name <> "Statistics" Then
            ' Call the subroutine to find the first peak in the current sheet
            Call FindFirstPeakInSheet(wsSource, firstPeak, foundPeak)

            ' Output the first peak or a message if no peak found
            If foundPeak Then
                wsResults.Cells(resultRow, 4).Value = firstPeak ' Output the first peak in column D
            Else
                wsResults.Cells(resultRow, 4).Value = "No peak found"
            End If

            ' Move to the next row for the next sheet's result
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
        End If
    Next wsSource
End Sub

If you have some ideas or suggestions how to change the code or write a new one you are welcome to share.

Can you share some data with Markdown tables to abe able to reproduce your issue? Anyways, this looks like more a math problem using the second derivative to check if a point is a local max/min

You say I tried to do something with derivative and slope but doesn't succeed Well, that the right approach.   Share that code, someone will help you fix it.

No data for testing, but try this. I assume that the x points are evenly spaced.
In auxiliary column C, calculate:
    wsSource.Cells(i, 3).Value = 2 * wsSource.Cells(i, 2).Value
        - wsSource.Cells(i - 1, 2).Value - wsSource.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value

And look for the maximum in this column.

So actually i friend of mine figure it out direct from excel "sintax" ( i don't know how to say it correctly) here you have it:
=(B47-B46)/(A47-A46);
=(D18-D17)/(A18-A17);
=IF(SIGN(D24)=1,IF(SIGN(A24)=1,IF(AND(D25*10<D24,SIGN(E24)=-1,SIGN(E25)=1),"min","-"),"y-neg"),"x-neg");
if i understand correct its doing a first derivative and the second derivative
tried to implement this in VBA Code but keep getting the error 438 in this section:
'''
If WorksheetFunction.Sign(D6) = 1 Then
'''
